# How do I use a lex scanner on a socket?

Tags: c, parsing, sockets, lex

Is it possible to use lex to scan/parse data from a socket? How do I go about defining the socket? Should it be SOCK_STREAM? Do I need to do anything fancy with my YY_INPUT macro, such as defining a select() loop to make sure there is data for the parser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using flex then you can redefine `YY_INPUT` to anything you want.

It should look like this:

```
#define YY_INPUT(buf,result,max_size)  \
read up to max_size characters into buf \
result = (read worked) ? (number of characters read) : YY_NULL;
```

Even if you have the characters somewhere in memory, you have to copy them into `buf`. That's a bit annoying, but it has to do with the fact that `flex` requires two NUL characters at the end of each input chunk, and it doesn't trust you to put them there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`fdopen(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fopen.3.html) on a `SOCK_STREAM`, i.e. a TCP, socket (you can't really do that on a UDP socket since you'll never get a `EOF`), though using sockets with [`stdio(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/stdio.3.html) streams is prone to issues, because of automatic double buffering (in kernel and in a stream).

You can look into rolling your own streams with [`fmemopen(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) or, if you are on Linux, even [`fopencookie(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fopencookie.3.html).